# "moving along/ahead/further between..."

Tags: adverbs

"Buses moving **along/ahead** *between* the repeated stops in front of the terminals."

Context. A street in front of an airport, with several bus stops, for each terminal following. Imagine LAX World Way from Terminal 4 to Terminal 8.

Question. I want to describe a bus moving from one stop to the other, in a way that depicts the action of stopping for each terminal, not passing by them.

For this I might use **between** stops. 
However, I don't want to sound as if the bus is moving back and forth between the stops. 
I hope I am comprehensible enough for you with my explanation.

I don't know how grammatically accurate it is using: ***moving along/ahead/further between...***

Thanks.

Comment: How about "shuttling from stop to stop"?

Comment: That would be exactly what I am trying to avoid, @mamster. I don't want to sound as though the bus is commuting to and fro between two stops. "Moving along between" would be the best way describing what I need to depict. It doesn't look too colloquial nevertheless.

Comment: “From stop to stop” suggests more than two stops to me, although “shuttling” is ambiguous. Proceeding?